# Invalid APK file when installing on my phone

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest, apk, adt

I have been working on a project for 3 months now, and everything was working.

Since yesterday however, Eclipse won't let me install my application on my phone. The application compiles fine, but when I try to run the program I get this error :

```
Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!
```

I have been looking for that error in Google and most people said it was a version problem. I set the uses-sdk version to 10, which is the platform on which I develop (and it has always worked before !).

When I check the logcat, I get this :

```
02-07 10:15:20.742: W/PackageParser(15356): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /data/local/tmp/App.apk
02-07 10:15:20.742: W/PackageParser(15356): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
02-07 10:15:20.742: W/PackageParser(15356):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
02-07 10:15:20.742: W/PackageParser(15356):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:486)
02-07 10:15:20.742: W/PackageParser(15356):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:454)
02-07 10:15:20.742: W/PackageParser(15356):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackageLite(PackageParser.java:601)
02-07 10:15:20.742: W/PackageParser(15356):     at com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService$1.getMinimalPackageInfo(DefaultContainerService.java:138)
02-07 10:15:20.742: W/PackageParser(15356):     at com.android.internal.app.IMediaContainerService$Stub.onTransact(IMediaContainerService.java:100)
02-07 10:15:20.742: W/PackageParser(15356):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
02-07 10:15:20.742: W/PackageParser(15356):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
02-07 10:15:20.781: W/DefContainer(15356): Failed to parse package
02-07 10:15:20.789: W/PackageParser(15356): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /data/local/tmp/App.apk
02-07 10:15:20.789: W/PackageParser(15356): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
02-07 10:15:20.789: W/PackageParser(15356):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
02-07 10:15:20.789: W/PackageParser(15356):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:486)
02-07 10:15:20.789: W/PackageParser(15356):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:454)
02-07 10:15:20.789: W/PackageParser(15356):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackageLite(PackageParser.java:601) 
02-07 10:15:20.789: W/PackageParser(15356):     at com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService$1.getMinimalPackageInfo(DefaultContainerService.java:138)
02-07 10:15:20.789: W/PackageParser(15356):     at com.android.internal.app.IMediaContainerService$Stub.onTransact(IMediaContainerService.java:100)
02-07 10:15:20.789: W/PackageParser(15356):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
02-07 10:15:20.789: W/PackageParser(15356):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
02-07 10:15:20.828: W/DefContainer(15356): Failed to parse package
```

I got the apk file from the bin folder, and when unziped it I found my AndroidManifest.xml inside it. I then checked the error status in Eclipse, and it says that Eclipse "Can't find file D:\xxx\xxx\xxx\AndroidManifest.xml in workspace". I also get the same error with a few xml layouts of the same project.
However I can see, open, edit and save those files in Eclipse, so I find it a bit odd that it could not find them.

Last thing, yesterday I could install my app again after doing a clean project AND restarting Eclipse, but it does not seem to work anymore and it is not a good solution (I can't make a clean and restart Eclipse every time I modify my code !).

Did you ever encountered this problem ? How could I solve it ?

Thanks !

Comment: try building your APK again, it happens from time to time

Comment: have you change you location of workspace/SDK or prject folder??

Comment: @Marek Sebera : I have already tried to clean the project and build it again many times, but this did not solve the problem

Comment: @Smith : I did not change anything as the project was working fine until now

Comment: ok..fine...have you changed package name of project?because it sounds from log cat that Failed to parse package.

Comment: are you installing signed apk if no then try to install sing apk on mobile. if u r using eclipse right click on project> android tools> exportsigned apk

Comment: This might also be expired certificate issue... delete your eclipse debug certificate.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem. Just try cleaning the project and rebuild. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try rebuilding your project from your old existing source

1. File New
2. Android Project
3. choose  **Create project from existing source**
4. then, below you can go to the repository of your project to select it

I had a similar problem once and it worked for me, I hope it will work for you

Comment: It worked once, but the problem came again and this time it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I ran out of disk space, freeing some space and cleaning the project solved the issue.